# Why does excel keep crashing when running the following vba code?

Tags: vba, excel

Whenever I run the code below, excel and VBA freeze and then crash after a few seconds of execution. I'm trying to figure out why and try to fix it. The relevant code is below:

```
            Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
            Dim i As Long, j As Long
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SomeSheet")
            Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SomeSheet2")

            i = 2
            j = 4
            For Each rw In ws2.Rows

                    While Not IsEmpty(ws2.Cells(1, j))
                        ws2.Cells(i, j).Value = (Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(ws.Range("P:P"), ws.Range("A:A"), "=" & ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value, ws.Range("C:C"), "=" & ws2.Cells(i, 2), ws.Range("E:E"), "=" & ws2.Cells(i, 3), ws.Range("J:J"), "=" & ws2.Cells(1, j))) / 8
                        Debug.Print i
                        Debug.Print j
                        j = j + 1
                    Wend
                    j = 4
                    i = i + 1
            Next rw
```

"SomeSheet" is a data sheet with around 50k rows. "SomeSheet2" is a table programatically filled with sumifs results from the data in "SomeSheet" based on the row and column of "SomeSheet2". The code starts freezing roughly after the 3rd row and the 25th column(i=3, j=25) and then crash completely. It's never at the same exact spot though. This makes me think that the problem is not the data. I thought that the problem might be related to the "sumifs" call but if I replace this line:

```
ws2.Cells(i, j).Value = (Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(ws.Range("P:P"), ws.Range("A:A"), "=" & ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value, ws.Range("C:C"), "=" & ws2.Cells(i, 2), ws.Range("E:E"), "=" & ws2.Cells(i, 3), ws.Range("J:J"), "=" & ws2.Cells(1, j))) / 8
```

with

```
ws2.Cells(i, j).Value = 1
```

It still crashes but later (i= ~50, j = ~60). I think it is related to Excel memory being filled up somehow but without knowing the limitations, I don't know how to code around it and accomplish what I want to do...

Comment: Does it actually crash or does it get "Not responding"?

Comment: it get "not responding". I don't have any error message or anything. I've tried to let it run for 1h to see if it would start responding again but it didn't.

Comment: After `For Each rw In ws2.Rows`, on the next line, insert a `DoEvents`. This will unlock excel when he gets not responding. However it will make the calculations slower. And if you do any input, or try to use another sheet, your code may have undesired effects

Comment: You could also insert after `While Not IsEmpty(ws2.Cells(1, j))`, but I think after `For each` is better.

Comment: I think doing both your suggestions fixed it somehow. If you put as an answer I'll mark as solution.

Comment: The `For Each rw ...` loop looks wrong — you code never does anything with `rw` and it looks like it will run to the last row (1048576?) of `ws2`. Try changing that to a loop on `i` with some test on when you've hit the real last row of `ws2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that excel has too much data to work with. Since it takes long, it *looks like* its not working, but it is actually running. It will eventually unfreeze.

However, you can add `DoEvents` so, every time the code executes this, it will give you back control of excel, making it work again.

But beware, since it gives you back the control, you can accidentally input data on one cell and this will make your code to stop. If this happens you will probably need to start over.

Also, this will make the code run slower. Making it take longer than it is already taking.